# User -> Worker. Database Model , Its possible to do this?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm currently making website for selling stuff and my system requires some specific user rank's to have workers under them. So i was thinking if it could be possible to make some database design like this ( See picture below) and add user_id with worker_id (foreign keys pointing to user_id key) and then retrieve through a query how many workers a user has.

Adding a picture to understand my idea.

Thanks.

[image: orm]

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.